# C# - Linq statement where skip last X rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a dynamic table where show/hide rows.

In this variable I skip first row, but I want skip last **n** rows...

```
var allVisibleRows1 = myTbl.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Where(row => row.Visible).Skip(1);
```

**(skip 1)** 2 3 4 5 **(skip 6)** **(skip 7)**

How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method and specify required count.

```
var allVisibleRows1 =myTbl.Rows.Cast<TableRow>()
                               .Where(row => row.Visible)
                               .Skip(1)
                               .Take(4); // specify count. Apply Math(if requied).
```

Comment: Follow up question, if you needed to skip lines 1,5 and 7 and get 2,3,4,6,8 for example. Will this be posible?

Comment: It is possible, but I suggest using overloaded `select` and supply index and then filter index based on our required indexes.

Comment: Okey, it seems out of my actual knowledge, but is good to know it's posible.

Comment: Hari Prasad, Thanks bro. :)

Answer (score 3):

Could you try this:

```
var allVisibleRows1 = myTbl.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Where(row => row.Visible);
LastNRowsSkipped = allVisibleRows1.Take(allVisibleRows1.Count() - N);
```

The only caveat with this is, we are enumerating over the collection twice -- Once for the count and once for filtering.

Comment: To avoid multiple enumerations, you could use: var allVisibleRows1 = myTbl.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Where(row => row.Visible).ToList();

Comment: Yes, that's better than enumerating twice.